# ¿Cómo cambiar una imagen con Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, jetpack-compose

estoy empezando con JetPack Compose y quiero hacer un reproductor de Audio, todo funciona bien, solo que en un `Box` tengo una imagen de la carátula de la canción y encima tengo un botón de play, al dar clic en la imagen reproduce y pausa, pero lo que quiero saber, si me ayudan, es como al hacer click en la imagen play esta misma cambie por la imagen pause

```
Image(
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.play),
    contentDescription = "Play",
    modifier = Modifier
        .clickable(onClick = {
            if (mp?.isPlaying == true) {
                mp?.pause()
            } else {

                mp?.play()
            }

        })
        .align(Alignment.Center)
        .width(50.dp)
        .height(50.dp)
)//Image
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jetpack Compose se basa en el paradigma de UI declarativa. En este paradigma, la UI es inmutable y por lo tanto no se puede hacer algo como cambiar una imagen. En cambio, cada modificación en el estado de tu app produce una nueva UI. Es decir, que lo que debes modificar no es la imagen sino el estado.

Para ello lo primero que necesitas es crear un estado que en tu caso podría llamarse `isPlaying`

```
var isPlaying by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

Esto crea un estado mutable con el valor inicial `false` (asumo que inicialmente la canción no se estará reproduciendo). Además está haciendo uso de delegados para que el estado se actualice automáticamete cuando cambies el valor de la variable. Para más detalles lee la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables).

El siguiente paso es definir que imagen generar en cada estado

```
val image = if (isPlaying) R.drawable.pause else R.drawable.play
```

Finalmente creas la imagen que corresponda con un `onClick` que actualice el valor de `isPlaying`

```
var isPlaying by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val image = if (isPlaying) R.drawable.pause else R.drawable.play
Image(
    painter = painterResource(image),
    contentDescription = "Play",
    modifier = Modifier
        .clickable {
            if (mp?.isPlaying == true) {
                mp.pause()
                isPlaying = true
            } else {
                mp?.play()
                isPlaying = false
            }
        }
        .align(Alignment.Center)
        .width(50.dp)
        .height(50.dp)
)//Image
```

Al cambiar un estado ocurre lo que compose llama [recomposition](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#recomposition), entonces todo ese código se vuelve ejecutar generando una nueva imagen en el mismo lugar donde estaba la anterior. Esto produce el mismo resultado que querías aunque es muy diferente conceptualmente. Para una mejor explicación ver [este video](https://youtu.be/Ef1xKWjA9E8?t=55).